# Persist Web Service Data in Xamarin App

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

In a business mobile app built in Xamarin that connects to a webservice to 'synchronize' data, what would be the best way to synchronize that data to the local storage?

We can use SQLite-NET + ServiceStack Client + custom programming to save the data that we get from the webservice into SQLite-NET tables/entities, however, we would like a framework that does it already (similar to what [RestKit](http://www.restkit.org) does).

Any framework or sample that could be used for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use SQLCipher from the Component Store to store locally for an encrypted sqllite database.

If you want some kind of Auto Sync framework, Zumero offers something similar to what you want.  You have to use their servers for it, but they have been talking about a Sync framework compatible with Azure hosted services.  Not sure on their ETA for releasing an Azure supported sync framework tool.

Zumero's component is listed as "Zumero SQLite".

Personally, with my current project, I couldn't use Zumero, and I couldn't wait for their component.. so I just moved forward.. used SQLCipher.. and made a manual sync process.

Worked pretty well.